# Why my RDLC report is not getting populated with latest data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset, rdlc

I have an rdlc report which is loading data from database table via Datatable but problem is that it only shows 27 records, not more. Even the sql table and datatable in c# has populated data but not populating in RDLC report.

I have used same code and same problem everywhere.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //ASP.controls_resultlabel_ascx ResultLabel = new ASP.controls_resultlabel_ascx();

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {


            Fill_AuditsReport();


        }
    }


    public void Fill_AuditsReport() 
        {
            ReportViewer1.AsyncRendering = false;
            ReportViewer1.SizeToReportContent = true;
            ReportViewer1.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.FullPage;
            this.ReportViewer1.Reset();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            Audits.ManageAudits MngAudits = new Audits.ManageAudits();

            dt = MngAudits.SelectAuditsInfo();

            ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/DataManagementReports/AuditsReport.rdlc");
            ReportDataSource rpds = new ReportDataSource("DataSetAudits", dt);
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rpds);
            ReportViewer1.Visible = true;
        }
```

Even datatable is getting populated with full data while debugging.

Comment: Is there a filter set on the table/matrix in the rdlc file that is filtering the data?  What about a row group filtering the data?

Comment: no no condition but only grouping by Name in first column

Comment: Is the grouping combining rows with the same Name?

Comment: yes, If your name is tyler then it will show ll record that belongs to tyler and your name willl appear one time, and then for next name next records

Comment: Is that why it is only showing 27 records.  Your datatable may have 100 records, but only 27 unique names and grouping contracts it down to show just 27 records.  Or is it not displaying some names that exist in the datatable?

Comment: no no sir, those reocrd are also relevant to same name but doesn't show up